# ASP.NET MVCで、ActionFilterの中からControllerのプロパティに値をセットしたい

Tags: c#, asp.net

お世話になっています。

ASP.NET MVCで、共通の基本Classを継承する複数のControllerがあり、いずれも同じActionFilterが設定されています。

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public MemberParam  mParam;
}

[AnalyseSession]
public class MemberController : BaseController
{
    // some codes
}

[AnalyseSession]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    // some codes
}
```

AnaliseSession アクションフィルタ内部で、呼び出したControllerの内部プロパティに値をセットしたいです。

```
public class AnalyseSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
        var sessions    = context.HttpContext.Session;
        // セッションを取得してうんちゃらします
        // ここがわからない部分
        var controller = context.Controller as MemberController;
        controller.mParam = this.mParam;
    }
}
```

単一のコントローラなら、見たとおり問題な参照できますが、複数コントローラ・多数のプロパティの場合、シンプルに実装する方法をご教示ください。

Comment: `context.Controller as MemberController`ではなく`context.Controller as BaseController`ではダメなのですか？

Comment: うわっ！そうですよね、そうですよね。ポリもーフィズムなんだ。
テストしてみたら一発でOKでした。

Answer (score 1):

上記のコメントを元に、自己レスとして回答しておきます。

```
public class AnalyseSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
    var sessions    = context.HttpContext.Session;
    // セッションを取得してうんちゃらします
    // ポリモーフィズムを用い、継承元クラスにキャストする
    var controller = context.Controller as BaseController;
    controller.mParam = this.mParam;
}
```